# How to add child to view controller swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Im trying to add an image to a specific coordinate on the view controller, I already imported SpriteKit to see if that could help. I just need to add the image and be able to move it on a UIBezierPath but it wont let me add Child.

```
    var blueDot = SKSpriteNode()
    var blackDot = SKSpriteNode()
    var levelLabelInt = levelLabel.text!.toInt()

    var blueDotTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Sprites.atlas/BlueDot.png")
    blueDot = SKSpriteNode(texture: blueDotTexture)
    blueDot.position = CGPoint(x: (50), y: levelLabelInt! + 100)
    self .addChildViewController: ViewController (blueDot)
```

Comment: If your trying to add an image to a view, why are you using Spritekit? You have an image, right (BlueDot.png)? Add an image view to your controller's view, and set its image. What you say you want to do has nothing to do with either SpriteKit or adding a child view controller.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the `code` above, one of your issues is a space between `self` and `.addChildViewController`

In Swift to send a message to `self` you have to use .dotSyntax. and the `addChild()` function requires an argument of type `UIViewController`

`self.addChild(blueDot)` syntax is correct but blueDot is of type: `SKNode` and `SKNode` doesn't inherit from UIViewController so you can't pass that argument.

I suggest you do this instead:

```
    let image = UIImage(named: "Sprites.atlas/BlueDot.png")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Now you have an image inside your ViewController's views hierarchy or as you prefer to refer to it: a child object inside your parent object.