# Use of unresolved identifier 'addChild'

Tags: ios, swift, addchild

would anyone be able to help where I can insert my highscoreLabel, I keep generating errors, I've looked at moving the code to viewDidAppear and viewDidLoad.

I'm just starting out with swift so if anyone can help that would be great.

Thank you.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
import GameKit

class StatsViewController: UIViewController {

var highScoreLabelNode = SKLabelNode()
var highScore = NSInteger()
var highscoreDefault = NSInteger()

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

            let highscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let score = highscoreDefault.valueForKey("HighScore")

    highScoreLabelNode.fontName = "Helvetica-Bold"
    highScoreLabelNode.position = CGPoint(x: 2.48, y: 1.17 )
    highScoreLabelNode.fontSize = 30
    highScoreLabelNode.alpha = 0.7
    highScoreLabelNode.text = "Highscore \(score)"

    addChild(highScoreLabelNode) //USE OF UNRESOLVED IDENTIFIER 'ADDCHILD'

}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        }

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}



override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error, you should see that the issue lies in that addChild is not a function, so placing it in other functions will not resolve this issue. You need to call the correct function on the view of your view controller.

Based on the answer to the question linked below, I believe you need to:

```
self.view.addSubview(highScoreLabelNode)
```

[How to add child to view controller swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396659/how-to-add-child-to-view-controller-swift)